# JBoss 7.1.1 Final Jasperreports 4.0.2 as a module

Tags: jboss7.x

I am trying this new class loading feature of JB7, witch sounds pretty good and i want to implement in a new project, but i am kinda stuck at this point... this is what i got:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="net.sourceforge.jasperreports">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="commons-javaflow-20060411.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="iText-2.1.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jasperreports-4.0.2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jcommon-1.0.15.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jfreechart-1.0.14.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.beanutils"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collection"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.digester" slot="1.7"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Without the `<module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>` dependency, the trace stack was showing an error of it being missing, even when this particular jar is already being deployed with the application by default, so i took out the jar from the app java libs folder and made a module for it, now my application hangs when the module net.sourceforge.jasperreports is needed, is there something am i missing?

This is the JBoss-deployment-structure if needed:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
            <module name="net.sourceforge.jasperreports"/>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
        </dependencies>
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="."/>
        </resources>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Its a Java EE project deploying as a war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have `<module name="org.apache.commons.collection"/>`
And sould be `<module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>`

And that was it... "-.-

Its weird because, when a module in Jboss sctructure fails to load, the war deployment fails and shows an error in the console, in this case it should be something about "org.apache.commons.collection not found" but somehow, my app was running normally, and any jasper report sevlet used was hanging eternally because of this missing module dependency.

Edit: `Jboss` doesn't show any error when a dependency is missing, it just hangs in that line. But it does show an error when a module fails to load resources.